# Image description on mouse hover like link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add some text on image hover in my site's images; When mouse cursor goes on the image, Show some text about that image.
I want to add some description about that image.
But i want box be as is on this site:
http://libeskind.com/work/
Please see link, and tell me how can i do that pls?

**I want that be as like as link example**
Thanks all

Comment: Do you Google it first.

Comment: I couldn't find any answer for that i wanted...

Comment: This is commonly done and very easy to do - Google it, most of us did.

Comment: Try for Gallery plugin

Comment: @Mamul - just search "image text overlay on hover".

Comment: I found image hover easily, but as like as that link, i didn't found... Let me know link pls!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is an easy job check out my example , i just made a simple example i did not added transition's as i think it will help you in learning , try to understand the code it is really easy.

```css
.imgc{width:100px;}
.imgc img{height:200px}
.imgc p {position:absolute;transition:1s all;padding:10px;background:#ddd;width:240px;display:none;margin-top:-20px}
.imgc:hover > p{display:block;}
```

```html
<div class='imgc'>
    <img src='http://libeskind.com/wp-content/uploads/aerial-view-c-guenter-schneider-555x426.jpg' />
    
    <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
```